# Soldering Iron and Electrostatic Bracelet Connection

Tags: soldering, ground, esd, electrostatic

I have a DIY soldering station and I want to ground the soldering iron and I also want to use a electrostatic bracelet connector for the soldering station.
Can you please help me how to connect the soldering iron's ground to the ground and how to connect the electrostatic bracelet to the ground of the soldering station ? I know that there have to be a resistor, but I do not know how to connect that resistor...

Comment: Show us the soldering iron mains plug. Does it have an earth pin and is there electrical continuity between it and the tip of the iron?

Comment: The current soldering iron is a Pensol Iron-N, which does not have continuity between the tip and the connector, but I will buy a new soldering iron, Pensol IronE-N, which has continuity between the tip and the connector. Both soldering irons have DIN5 connector and are powered at 24Vac.

Comment: I found that the ground pin is the central pin of the DIN5 connector, but I don't know if I need to use 1MOhm resistor for the soldering iron or if I need to use the 1MOhm resistor only for the connector for the electrostatic bracelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6l5Tt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Earth strap wiring.*

Normal practice is to wire the earth strap to the earth pin of a separate plug. The two are then connected via the mains earth.

Comment: The "Strap" means the electrostatic bracelet ?

Comment: Correct. You don't interfere with the soldering iron earth although you could add a strap connection point to it, if required.

Comment: The second problem is that I have a single mains connector on the soldering station. Can this connector be the point of connection of the 2 ground wires ?

Comment: Use your head! Get an adaptor or socket strip if you need a second power point.

Comment: Every soldering station has a body that is grounded. And it usually has a one-pin connector or screw to attach the strap. Why would you need any additional mains connector?

Comment: I've used Antex and Metcal soldering stations. I don't remember a ground screw on any of them. In Ireland the humidity is high enough that static isn't much of a problem.